# Funcion para obtener uuid version 7 en sql server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, uuid

Estoy intentando sacar un funcion para SQL Server 2019 que me devuelva un uuid en version 7.
He buscado y parece que no hay nada nativo. Lo unico encuentro es la funcion NEWID() pero esta me devuelve de forma nativa uuid V4.

Buscando he encontrado en este link:

[uuid v7 - mysql](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-18094/SQL-column-display-type-auto-detection-doesnt-work-for-UUIDv7)

Una funcion que hace el proceso pero para MYSQL. La he probado y parace correcta. Este es un ejemplo de uuid que devuelve:

018ad5a0-26f7-7f45-b0f0-8da517e7d371

018ad5a0-b707-73a4-a3ea-af7dac78ac72

018ad5a1-0545-776e-8ccc-583a6edb513b

018ad5a1-3d50-7e3c-9c80-dfd5b0b7fd07

Y si los valido en esta otra web parecen ser uuid V7 correctos

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.javainuse.com/uidvalidate)

Estoy intentando adaptar la funcion a SQL Server. Me estoy encontrado con varias funciones que no son equivalantes entre MYSQL y SQL SERVER. Voy a ir intentando adaptarla. Voy a ir poniendo por aqui avances por si alguien quiere ir colaborando (Yo he trabajado poco con SQL Server). En todo caso no se si existira otra opcion de hacerlo. La funcion MYSQL seria:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION UUID7()
  RETURNS CHAR(36)
BEGIN
  DECLARE timestamp CHAR(12);
  DECLARE h1 CHAR(8);
  DECLARE h2 CHAR(4);
  DECLARE h3 CHAR(3);
  DECLARE h4 CHAR(4);
  DECLARE h5 CHAR(12);

  SET timestamp = LPAD(HEX( ROUND( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4) ) * 1000) ), 12, '0');

  -- 1th and 2nd block are made of 6 bytes containing timestamp in milliseconds
  SET h1 = SUBSTR(timestamp, 1, 8);
  SET h2 = SUBSTR(timestamp, 9, 4);

  -- 3th block will start with a 7 indicating the version, remaining is random
  SET h3 = SUBSTR(HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(2)), 2, 3);

  -- 4th block first nibble can only be 8, 9 A or B, remaining is random
  SET h4 = CONCAT(HEX(FLOOR(ASCII(RANDOM_BYTES(1)) / 64) + 8), SUBSTR(HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(2)), 2, 
  3));

 -- 5th block is made of 6 random bytes
  SET h5 = HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(6));

  -- Build the complete UUID
  RETURN LOWER(CONCAT(h1, '-', h2, '-7', h3, '-', h4, '-', h5));
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Para la funcion SQL Server he avanzado hasta conseguir del primer SET timestamp hasta el ROUND.

Quedaria asi

```
SELECT ROUND(DATEDIFF_BIG(MILLISECOND,'1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', SYSUTCDATETIME()), 0);
```

Me he quedado bloqueado en la funcion HEX (no veo nada nativo en SQL SERVER 2019)...

Si alguien quiere dar una mano bienvenida sea.

Ire actualizando el tema segun pueda o podamos avanzar.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez estoy cometiendo algún error (en especial en los bytes del tiempo que tal vez requieren usar `RIGHT()`), pero generé varios valores y pasaron la validación en la página que compartiste. Para generar valores hexadecimales usé la función `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(n)` que tiene básicamente la misma funcionalidad que `HEX(n)` de MySQL.

En vez de calcular parte por parte, agrupé todo y al final agregué los guiones en el lugar que corresponden. El código tiene comentarios para indicar la funcionalidad de cada renglón.

```
SELECT STUFF( 
            STUFF( 
                STUFF( 
                    STUFF( 
                        LOWER( 
                            CONCAT(
                                    SUBSTRING( BinaryTimeStamp, 1, 12), -- Tomamos los 6 bytes del tiempo
                                    RIGHT( CONVERT( varchar(10),  CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2), 2), 3), -- Generamos 2 bytes de los cuales tomamos 3 caracteres
                                    RIGHT( CONVERT( char(2), CONVERT( varbinary(1), ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%4 + 8),2), 1), -- Generamos un número aleatorio entre 8 y 11 (B)
                                    RIGHT( CONVERT( varchar(30),  CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8), 2), 15) -- Generamos los bytes restantes
                                    ) -- Se unen todas las cadenas
                                ) -- Se convierte a minúsculas
                            , 20, 0, '-') -- Agregamos el último guion
                        , 16, 0, '-') -- Agregamos el tercer guion
                    , 13, 0, '-7') -- Agregamos el segundo guion con un 7
                , 9, 0, '-') --Agregamos el primer guion
FROM ( VALUES(CONVERT( varchar(100),  CONVERT( varbinary(MAX),  DATEDIFF_BIG( MS, '19700101', SYSDATETIME())), 2)))x(BinaryTimeStamp); --Obtenemos los milisegundos desde 1970-01-01 a la fecha
```

Esto fácilmente se puede convertir en una vista que se une con `CROSS JOIN` para poder obtener los valores fácilmente. Esto es por las limitaciones que tienen las funciones.

```
CREATE VIEW Genera_UUIDv7
AS
SELECT STUFF( 
            STUFF( 
                STUFF( 
                    STUFF( 
                        LOWER( 
                            CONCAT(
                                    SUBSTRING( BinaryTimeStamp, 1, 12), -- Tomamos los 6 bytes del tiempo
                                    RIGHT( CONVERT( varchar(10),  CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(2), 2), 3), -- Generamos 2 bytes de los cuales tomamos 3 caracteres
                                    RIGHT( CONVERT( char(2), CONVERT( varbinary(1), ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%4 + 8),2), 1), -- Generamos un número aleatorio entre 8 y 11 (B)
                                    RIGHT( CONVERT( varchar(30),  CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8), 2), 15) -- Generamos los bytes restantes
                                    ) -- Se unen todas las cadenas
                                ) -- Se convierte a minúsculas
                            , 20, 0, '-') -- Agregamos el último guion
                        , 16, 0, '-') -- Agregamos el tercer guion
                    , 13, 0, '-7') -- Agregamos el segundo guion con un 7
                , 9, 0, '-') --Agregamos el primer guion
                                AS UUID
FROM ( VALUES(CONVERT( varchar(100),  CONVERT( varbinary(MAX),  DATEDIFF_BIG( MS, '19700101', SYSDATETIME())), 2)))x(BinaryTimeStamp); --Obtenemos los milisegundos desde 1970-01-01 a la fecha
```

Y su uso quedaría algo similar a esto.

```
SELECT u.UUID, o.*
FROM sys.objects o
CROSS JOIN Genera_UUIDv7 u;
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Muchas gracias!!!